# How to use rtnl and spinlock for synchronization?

Tags: multithreading, locking, ipc

Can any one explain about RTNL( rtnl_lock() rtnl_unlock() ) I tried google but unable to dig much

What I got from net is RTNL is Netlink used for communication like IPC bet user and kernel space but I didn't get more than that

I got something about spinlock() like why spinlock is better than semaphore, but not too much

But it would be really helpful if somebody explain something about RTNL

Any link for details would be much appreciated.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because SO is not a documentation repeating, nor is it "gimme linkz" site.

Answer (score 0):

Although a bit late, but it's a global lock that protects netdev from race conditions when multiple users try to change it (e.g. concurrent config changes to same interface from user space.)

In netdev conference 2.2 (2017) there's a talk called [*RTNL mutex, the network stack big kernel lock*](https://youtu.be/M6RiQGNz4HE), which basically explained everything you need to know about it.